# Delphi crSQLWait mouse cursor issue

Tags: multithreading, delphi, mouse-cursor

We have legacy delphi application in which entire code is in main thread only. In one of the function, we are calling service layer function to fetch database records. Before requesting the service layer, default cursor is changing to SQL WAIT cursor and after receiving the response cursor is reverting back to default cursor.

But while running the application (invoking this function), application is showing SQL WAIT cursor for 3 seconds and then application is going into NOT RESPONDING state and SQL WAIT cursor is changing to normal windows WAIT cursor.

Can anyone suggest why this issue is occurring and how to fix this? We can do threading to eliminate this but I should not implement threads newly in this code.

Comment: My best guess would be that it's related to window ghosting. Since the actual windows displayed after it goes unresponsive isn't one from your application, but a "ghost" generated by the OS, that could explain why you get a different cursor. You could try calling DisableProcessWindowsGhosting (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-disableprocesswindowsghosting) on startup to test the theory. If it is the source of the problem, you should get the right cursor even after it goes "not responding". Note that I don't necessarily advise that as a solution.

Comment: @KenBourassa, Is there any other way instead of completely disabling windows process ghosting? Actually Windows process ghosting introduced in Windows Server 2003. But we are not facing this issue while running the application in Windows Server 2003 R2. While running the same application in Windows Server 2012 R2 / Windows Server 2016, we are facing the issue.

Comment: Well... One way would be to run the SQL in a thread and have main thread keep processing messages. But that would bring it's own set of issues. By the way, it's unclear from your comment whether or not you tested the theory...

Comment: As you suggested, I have tested the application and after the change application is not going to not responding state. But I am not supposed to do any changes in the code level as the same application is working with no issues in Windows server 2003 R2. It would be helpful if there is any way to add windows registry entry for this application in new servers?